# NSManagedObjectContext starts with value and become null

Tags: xcode, core-data, ios6, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have just started developing iPad apps and I'm struggling with an issue for too long now, so I've decided to go for help.

I have an application for iPad using storyboard and started as a Tabbed application using CoreData. So the issue is, my NSManagedObjectContext starts with a value but when I move to another tab, the managedObjectContext becomes null.

Don't know what to do. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Elkucho

Comment: Are you passing the managedObjectContext to each tab that needs access to it?

Comment: I think so. Each controller have the managedObjectContext. Like I said, I'm new to this stuff and this might be one of those "duh" moments after I found out what it is.

Comment: Each controller may have a `managedObjectContext` property but are you actually populating it at any point?

Comment: I don't believe so. I have the following line in all my .h files.@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext; Besides that, I am not sure how to populate them. Sorry for the basic questions but this is bothering me for the whole weekend.

Comment: Can you show the code in your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: Sure, here it is...                                                   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    L4MainViewController *controller = (L4MainViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm slightly confused...

```
self.window.rootViewController
```

should return your instance of `UITabBarController`, which should not respond to `setManagedObjectContext:` and therefore should crash.

With this in mind what you need to do it

1. Get the tabBarController
2. Cycle through the viewController's that the tabBarController manages
3. Pass them the managedObjectContext

   ```
   for (id viewController in self.window.rootViewController.viewControllers) {
     [viewController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
   }
   ```

### Edit

I've taken a quick look.

- You rarely need to subclass `UITabBarController` and you don't really need to in this case.
  What you want to do is just get the `managedObjectContext` to each of the viewControllers in the tabBarController, the tabBarController itself does need to know about it.

I changed your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to the following and it worked the way it was supposed to

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  UITabBarController *tabBarController = (id)self.window.rootViewController;

  for (id viewController in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
    [viewController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
  }
}
```

Comment: I started the application as an "Utility Application" and everything was working ok. I then added TabBar Controller. That's when the managedObjectContext starting to get null as value. Basically I don't know where to add the code.

Comment: In the app delegate where replacing the first two lines you showed

Comment: Yeah man, I can't make it work.  If you could, I can send you the whole app. I don't want you to do it for me but I believe it might have more relevant information other than what I have given you. If no, I understand. Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: Please try the following https://github.com/elkucho/firstApp              I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Oh man, worked perfectly. I really appreciate your help. Now, I'll get back to this app and get my learning going. Thanks again.

Comment: If my answer helped/solved your problem then hit the accept button